# Uber server token are not working any more, How to generate new server token

Tags: uber-api

Uber server token are not working any more, on dashboard it shows "Please reach out to your Uber BD Representative for server token access."

Comment: The same has just happened to my app in the last few days.  It seems Uber is changing API access and has done some sort of purge which forces getting access through some approved "Business Development" rep or process.  I don't have a formal answer for you as I too am trying to navigate this new problem.

Comment: Hi @rolinger please let me know if you found any solution, thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue, were you guys able to solve it ?

Comment: same issue here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an issue for Uber customer service, not a question about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 2):

It seems Uber is changing API access and has done some sort of purge which forces getting access through some approved "Business Development" rep or process.

You can read [this page](https://developer.uber.com/support), that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead without adding Server Token your app will work properly.
In the past, I also faced this problem but without adding server token my app started working properly.