# Uber throwing Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided with a Server Token

Tags: uber-api

Did anyone using Uber Api on the server side notice that some endpoints are throwing an "Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided" where there is no need for a user access token ?
It used to work fine up until few days ago.

Here is an example of a call :

```
https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/time?start_latitude=48.8926537&start_longitude=2.3184883
```

headers :

```
"Accept":"application/json,
"Content-Type":"application/json",
"Authorization":"Token server-token-here",
"User-Agent":"axios/0.18.0"
```

Documentation says that this endpoint in particular should work with either a server token or a user access token :

> Server token or OAuth 2.0 user access token with any valid scope.

Response :

```
{  
   "status":401,
   "statusText":"Unauthorized",
   "data":{  
      "code":"unauthorized",
      "message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided."
   }
}
```

They've also added this notice at the top of documentation but I'm not sure what this means, and I did not receive any email announcing a change in access polices.

> Notice As part of Uber’s ongoing privacy improvements, we’re upgrading
>   our Developer API program with new access policies for third party
>   applications.
>
> Developers previously using our public APIs have been contacted and we
>   will continue to evaluate access on a case by case basis.

Anyone knows what's happening ?

Comment: [Maybe duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738976/uber-server-token-are-not-working-any-more-how-to-generate-new-server-token), There is a link to a post on twitter that you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

The same is just happening to everyone in the last few days. It seems Uber is changing API access and has done some sort of purge which forces getting access through some approved "Business Development" rep or process.

They don't have contact form, so i suggest you to post on Twitter if you want to ask them.

You can read the [support page](https://developer.uber.com/support) too.